# Connecting Flutter to the a local nodejs socket server

Tags: node.js, sockets, flutter, dart, socket.io

I am developing a chat part form my app and I coded a basic socket server with node js and socket.io.

I tested this API with this site: https://www.websocket.org/echo.html

Here is some source code :

```
  var server = require('http').Server(app)
  var io = require('socket.io')(server);

  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true,
    limit: '50mb',
  })); 
  app.use(bodyParser.json());
  app.use("/f",express.static(__dirname+"/files"));
  app.use('/api', listenRoutes);


  io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('a user connected');
    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
      console.log('user disconnected');
    });
  });

  server.listen(port);


  console.log('Bukalemun RESTful API server started on: ' + port);
```

My API is served on http://localhost:3000

However I am having trouble connecting this API to my flutter app. I used various types of packages including original dart.io but I never succeeded.

This is the function to connect my API:

```
import 'dart:io';

  void setupSocketConnections() async {

    Socket socket = await Socket.connect('10.0.2.2', 3000);

    print('connected');

    // listen to the received data event stream
    socket.listen((List<int> event) {
      print(utf8.decode(event));
    });

    // send hello
    socket.add(utf8.encode('hello'));

    // wait 5 seconds
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5));

    // .. and close the socket
    socket.close();

  }
```

I would be grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: are there errors in your console?

Comment: @Peter No there is not, I just don't get a "a user connected" log from my api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose this was a localhost related error. The problem resolved when I deployed my server to heroku and connected it via this library https://pub.dev/packages/adhara_socket_io#-readme-tab-

I shared my basic client example here : https://github.com/isaturk66/dart_socket_client_example

Server side is a basic socket.io server there is already documentation on their official site : https://socket.io/docs/

Comment: Well done mate, but you didn't have to deploy it remotely... You just have to enable port forwarding in on your machine, you can do it via your chrome browser or any other chromium-based browser, I'm not sure if other browsers do it though.

Answer (score 2):

Try using this mostly you might have used some headers with the sockets as .

```
'transports': ['websocket', 'polling']
```

Use this dependency in your `pubspec.yaml`

```
[socket_io_client: ^0.9.7+2][1]
```

Well use this code to connect in your flutter app.

```
connectToSocket() {
socket = IO.io("http://your url/", <String, dynamic>{
  'transports': ['websocket', 'polling'],
});
socket.connect();
```

}

Hope it works for you ! It has worked for me.

Comment: Your answer is not easy to understand.

Comment: let me know if you need my code so that it could help you out

Comment: Yees! The 'polling' transport property did the trick for me!